# sort $array by $array['value'] Desc

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can i do that?    example i have an `$array` where i use `$array['name']` and `$array['value']` i can i sort the `$array` by one of the atributes and choose ASC / DESC ?

Comment: So you `$array['name']` and `$array['value']` are arrays themselves where `$array['name'][<KEY>]` corresponds to `$array['value'][<KEY>]` ?

Comment: Could you give an example of your array? The way it is described, your array has only two entries (with keys `name` and `value`) and saying you want to sort it be `value` does not make sense in this context. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To sort an associative array according to the key of the array, you can use the ksort() function in the following manner:

```
<?php

$narray["IBM"]="International Business Machines";
$narray["MS"]="Microsoft";
$narray["CA"]="Computer Associated";
$narray["WHO"]="World Health Organization";
$narray["UK"]="United Kingdon";
$narray["BA"]="Something Random";

ksort($narray);

foreach($narray as $key => $value)
{
print $key . " = " . $value . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Similarly, you can sort an associative array according to the key, in ascending order by using the krsort() function.

Source: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/sorting_array.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort`:

```
function my_array_sorter($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($my_array, 'my_array_sorter');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you are using associative arrays:

```
arsort($array)
```

`asort` sorts values, `arsort` in reverse.

`ksort` sorts keys, `krsort` in reverse.